# Adding image upload to html page (mysql backend)

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

Relatively new to web development here, but am trying to implement an image upload feature, the contents of which will be previewed to the person (administrator) uploading the image, and then stored in a database (and displayed to the end user on a different page).

I found a resource that uses a Imageshack API, and was a bit confused about what this is and how the person implemented the API to achieve the image upload. The code for this is here: http://www.sceditor.com/posts/how-to-upload-and-insert-an-image/

When I googled "Imageshack API," I kept running across something that said I need to request a key. What does this mean, and do I have to do it? Is this the easiest way to go about creating an image upload feature for my purposes?

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

Imageshack API is for uploading image files to your account hosted at Imageshack.com. It seems that you want to upload image files to your own website and store such files on your own web servers (either in a cloud service such as AWS or your co-located/managed servers at some data centres). So, you probably do not want to use Imageshack.

As to how to upload image files using HTML & PHP, you may want to check out a short tutorial at:
www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Also, by the way, storing image files into a database such as MySQL may not be a good idea -- image files should be stored as files. It is faster to access such image files on a web server than to access image contents stored in a database.